# How do I resolve the: Please install Android target: "android-25" issue?

Tags: android, meteor, path

When I run `meteor run android` I see the below error message:

[image: Image displaying the error message shown after the command <code>meteor run android</code> is written]

When I write: `echo $ANDROID_HOME` I get:

/home/sirbt/Android/Sdk

When I write: `echo $PATH` I get:

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/sirbt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/sirbt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/sirbt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/sirbt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/sirbt/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`

According to this article from: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8464 Its suggested that one can replace the **tool** folder in `Android/Sdk` with `tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip` from: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip Which i have done, to no avail!

My working environment is:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- OS type: 32-bit
- Meteor 1.5

Comment: Use the Android SDK Manager to install the Android 7.1.1 (API Level 25) edition of the Android SDK. You can get to the Android SDK Manager from Android Studio. Or [use the `sdkmanager` command-line utility](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. Your advise worked. How do I credit you?

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. Your advise worked. How do I credit you?

Comment: Don't worry about that. What you might want to do, though, is post an answer to your own question, where you explain what you did in terms that somebody coming from Meteor will understand, in hopes that your question and answer will help the next Meteor developer that runs into this issue.